# python why some modules are defined on win and not on linux

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, pycharm

I start to write python script

I use the pyCharm or VS 2010 as editor

And then I copy the script from win to my Linux machine

I have on my Linux machine python version 2.4.3
And on my win machine I installed python version 3.4

What I see is that some modules are exists in the Linux machine
As

```
    import commands
```

and not exist on the python that installed on my win machine in spite the python version on my win version is higher

so my question is what is the suggestion to build on my win machines all the missing modules

because the idea to write script directly on my linux machine VIA vi is very bad

Comment: That particular module was [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) years ago and removed in Python 3.  Is your question just about that particular module, or other modules as well?

Comment: its about all other module ,

Comment: I just want to verify that all module that are on my win are also supported on my linux - is it possible to compare that

Comment: all my question is come because when I write script on my VS  then copy them to my Linux then I see that some modules on Linux are not as on my win machine

Comment: how to solve this? , or maybe other idea how to write on VS and then run it on linux

Comment: It's not just a matter of Windows vs Linux.  You're running *different versions* of Python on the two systems, so many things will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs, 'commands' is depracated since version 2.6.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#module-commands

They suggest using the 'subprocess' module instead..
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: as I know on my linux machine subprocess module not installed

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "can you assume that any module available on one computer is available on another", the answer is obviously no.  There could be third-party libraries installed on one computer but not the other.  Even if your question is "can you assume that any builtin module available on one computer is available on another", the answer is still no, since there are platform-specific modules.

Finally, even if all the same modules were available, that doesn't mean your code will work.  You can't expect code you wrote for Python 3 to work on Python 2 at all.  You can write code that will work on both versions of Python, but you'll have to plan for it and write your code carefully with that in mind, in addition to ensuring that you only use libraries available on both systems.